# Elements of 2d interger arrays not getting compared. not trying to compare the whole array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm just brushing up on my java skills because its been a while since I have coded. I have looked at many posts of my question and found that I seem to be comparing everything correctly as far as I can tell. I am comparing two 2d array elements against each other and if that match I replace the character at the element, However it seems to just go out of bounds when trying to compare them. Not seeing the out of bounds error (line 48).

```html
char[][] board = new char[3][3];
char[][] player1 = new char[1][1];
char[][] player2 = new char[1][1];
int playerRow = 0;
int playerCol = 0;
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in); 

System.out.println("Lets play a simple game of tic-tac-toe");
        System.out.println("Player 1 (X's) : Please enter a row number and column number ");
        System.out.println(" in order to plot the cordinates of your desired move");
        playerRow = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        playerCol = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < board[row].length;col++)
            {
                if (board[row][col] == player1[playerRow][playerCol])
                {
                    board[row][col] = 'X';
                    System.out.print(board[row][col]+" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    board[row][col]= '-';
                    System.out.print(board[row][col]+" ");

                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: You're comparing a `char` to an `int`. That's a valid comparison, but probably doesn't do what you want. For example, `'1'` (char) is not the same as `1` (int).

Comment: whoops. oh my I look over that for like 45 minutes.

Comment: I changed that, however it keeps giving me an array index out of bounds error, I made the player arrays char arrays. is this okay? @resueman

Comment: also, you're declaring char arrays and initializing int arrays

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the error that you could post?

Comment: I don't, I don't have much experience with stack tracing. It just states I am getting an array index out of bounds on line 48. Though like you said it must be my arrays not being set up correctly which is causing this error ir presume?

Comment: So if the user enters cordinates 0 0 it gives me an error on 48..if the user enters 1 1 the error is on 49..so on and so on.

Comment: We can't know which one the lines 48 and 49 are in your code snippet. Is it `playerRow = kbd.next().charAt(0);`?

Comment: sorry no, it starts at 48 which would be the "if" statement.

Comment: It looks like `playerRow` and `playerColumn` are characters, because they are the product of a call to `charAt()`.  Later, you try to use them as list indices, in the line: `if (board[row][col] == player1[playerRow][playerCol])`.

Comment: ahh this could be the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to parse those values to Integers when assigning them.

Comment: Look at resueman's answer.

Comment: I did, I was so close! Thanks Verge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems like you're taking the wrong approach to solving this. Unless I'm misunderstanding your purpose, I don't think `player1` or `player2` are necessary. Everything should be stored just in `board`. Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
//initialize variables
char[][] board = new char[3][3];
int playerRow = 0;
int playerCol = 0;

//clear the board
for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++){
        board[row][col] = '-';
    }
}

Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Lets play a simple game of tic-tac-toe");
System.out.println("Player 1 (X's) : Please enter a row number and column number ");
System.out.println(" in order to plot the cordinates of your desired move");

//get player's row and column
playerRow = kbd.nextInt();
playerCol = kbd.nextInt();

//Change the chosen spot to be the player's character.
board[playerRow][playerCol] = 'X';

//Display the board
for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < board[row].length;col++){
        System.out.print(board[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

That's an example of one move, which lets the player pick a spot, and then displays the board.

The reason for the error you're currently getting is because you read in the character `'0'`, and then try to use that as an index into the array. But `'0'` is not the same as `0`; it's actually the unicode value representing the character `0`, which happens to have the value `48`, which is not a valid index into your array. You should take that input as an integer, and then simply set that value in the array (without the loops to find the correct spot).

Comment: Thank you all especially resueman and @vergeA. I always tend to convolute my programs chasing a rabbit hole of fixes stacked on top of one another. I was literally right where I needed to be but could not see it. Thank you guys. much love everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your player(i) 2-D arrays involve assigning a char 2-D array to an integer 2-D array.

char[][] player1 = new int[board.length][board.length];
char[][] player2 = new int[board.length][board.length];

I don't think it's a feasible initialization.

Also as mentioned in the above comments, you are comparing a char with an int.
Hence, it is trying to compare the integer value of your characters with the variable values being compared to.

Comment: Sorry that is a error in the code. the are correct the error still occurs.

Comment: Your board is a 3*3 2-D array whereas the players are just 1*1 and hence it's going out of bounds.

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense to me, what is my logic error here?

Comment: I have tried to make them 3 by 3 as well it still will go out of bounds.

Comment: He's not accessing the player arrays with `row` and `col` so that's not the problem

Comment: Did you try putting a break point at the         playerRow = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        playerCol = kbd.next().charAt(0); to make sure you are getting the right values here? Try using nextInt() instead of using next()